# How do i subract a number a specific amount of times?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have this exercise:
Create a while-loop that subtracts 8 from 34, 22 times. Answer with the
result.

I can subract 8 from 34, until it reaches 0, but how do I do it 22 times instead?

```py
MIN = 0

MAX = 34

while MIN < MAX:

    MAX = MAX -8

ANSWER = MAX
```

Thats how i did it to subtract until it hit 0. But now i need it 22 times, so until it reaches -142. But i want the code to tell me that it's at -142, like if i didn't know it was -142.

Comment: you just keep subtracting, you'll get a negative number but that's ok.

Comment: You'll want a variable to count how many times the loop has happened. Then you leave the `while` when that counter is the number you want it to be.

Comment: `32-8*22` but that's not a loop

Comment: The Python style guide says that [variable names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the condition of the while loop to only be True the first 22 times. The typical way of doing this is assigning a variable outside the loop, then having the loop compare that value to something else, and change it at the end of the loop.

```
i = 22
while i > 0:
    # do something
    i -= 1
```

This isn't a typical use of a while loop though. You would be better off using a for-loop if you know something has to happen a set number of times.

```
for _ in range(22):
    # do something
```

Side note: in fact this problem is bad even for a for-loop, because you can represent it just a maths:

```
v = 34
print(v - (8 * 22))
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep subtracting, for example, written your way:

```
TIMES = 22 RESULT = 34

while TIMES > 0: 

  RESULT = RESULT - 8
  TIMES = TIMES - 1

ANSWER = RESULT
```

I don’t do python though so sorry if the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Your indentation is not right

Comment: Python doesn't support decrement.

Comment: `I--` is not valid python